# Flash document viewer

Tags: flash, document, documentviewer

Is there a flash based document viewer? I am looking for something similar to iPaper that Scribd.com uses.

Answer (score 6):

There's a great open source viewer for PDF2SWF: http://www.devaldi.com/?page_id=260

Answer (score 2):

I've used **PDF2SWF** in the past to do basic document conversion/viewing in Flash: http://www.swftools.org/pdf2swf.html although I don't think they are as full featured as the iPaper and Scribd viewers - although it is entirely free to use.

You can download from here: http://www.swftools.org/download.html

It allows you to convert any PDF file into a multi-frame swf. You can optionally embed a viewer into the swf (comes with a simple and advanced viewer) or you could create your own if you want more advanced features.

This is an example document with the viewer: http://www.swftools.org/flash/paper5.html

Answer (score 1):

Print2Flash isn't bad. Check it out here:

http://print2flash.com/

There are some quirks with loading the assets sometimes but it works pretty well. It requires windows, MS Office, and Adobe Reader to support the popular formats (pdf, word, excel, etc.).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a situation where you’re using a device that can’t open PDF files, you can try to work around the problem with a tool that convert the PDF to a SWF online

I got a site to recommend http://www.axmag.com/submit.html either Upload your local or online PDF at this page.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Flashpaper, it installs as a printer on your machine and anything that you can print to paper can be viewed as a flash object and copied to any website.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashpaper/

It is not free, but I use it and think it is very good.

Whilst there are free online services such as what you listed, this is one that you own and can host yurself.

Comment: Flash paper has been end of life'd. They aren't supporting it, I wouldn't create a new product with it.