# How to create readonly viewer for Word, Excel and PDF-documents?

Tags: html, excel, pdf, ms-word

We need to set up a page to make some highly confidential documents (PDF, Excel, Word) available for viewing only.
The page/documents needs to be as secure as possible (no save, no print etc). We recon that we can't stop print-screen, but hopefully we can limit most of the other options.

How do you best do this? I have currently only two options that I am considering:

- Open the documents inside an IFrame and experiment with javascript and css
- Create a viewer in Silverlight (or Flash)

If any of you have some ideas on how to achieve this, please tell me. It will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you don't want an info or a document to be broadcasted. First, don't digitalize it. Second, don't put it on an internet page. Third, don't put it on an intranet page. Eventually, you could use a third-party solution (flash, silverlight or so)... find inspiration on similar website like http://www.scribd.com/

Comment: We want to broadcast it -thats the problem. But the information is so sensitive that we need to make sure that the users reading it is not able to save it and forward it.

Comment: Please be aware that even with a presentation medium like Flash or Silverlight the user can always use a screen-capture program like Camtasia - I don't know if it's possible to hinder Windows to capture the screen (as, for example, you can hinder it to copy a password from a password textbox).

Comment: We know that screenshots is hard to "defend" against. But it is most important that we can prevent saving or printing of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word and Excel don't offer a lot of security. I would convert everything you want secured into a PDF and use something like the PDF viewer referenced in this question: [Flash document viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219890/flash-document-viewer). It's an open source plugin that will allow you to disable save and print and should go a long way towards deterring users from attempting to copy the documents.