# read only pdf plugin for website

Tags: html, pdf

I am making a website in which I need to show content like PDFs, images, and presentations online. But requirements have been placed on me are that the content should not be downloadable and copy-pastable as far as possible. I have never used plugins to show PDFs etc. online before this, and I am confused about how to do it.

Websites like slideshare show presentations using some plugin and I want to do similar things but I am stuck with how to start. I followed [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219890/flash-document-viewer), and thought it's what I am looking for. But does PDF2SWF converts PDFs on the fly and shows it to users or do we need to convert each PDF manually and show it? Also, what about .doc files and .ppt files with PDF2SWF?

What should be my approach while meeting these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with google documents

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://yoursite.com/document.pdf&embedded=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" style="border: none;" width="800" height="470"></iframe>
```